# Reduce process time String decomposition

Tags: string, vba, performance, excel, outlook

I hope you can help me reduce the runtime of my code :

```
Dim position As Long
Dim CellRow As Long
CellRow = 2

For position = InStr(Inbox.Items(MostRecentVersionIndex).body, "Name") To Len(Inbox.Items(MostRecentVersionIndex).body)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & CellRow) = Mid(Inbox.Items(MostRecentVersionIndex).body, InStr(position, Inbox.Items(MostRecentVersionIndex).body, "SCA"), InStr(InStr(position, Inbox.Items(MostRecentVersionIndex).body, "SCA") + 1, Inbox.Items(MostRecentVersionIndex).body, "SCA") - InStr(position, Inbox.Items(MostRecentVersionIndex).body, "SCA"))
            CellRow = CellRow + 1
            position = InStr(InStr(position, Inbox.Items(MostRecentVersionIndex).body, "SCA") + 1, Inbox.Items(MostRecentVersionIndex).body, "SCA") - 1
        Next position
```

1. The first part of the code was to find a specific email in Outlook and then I stored its index in `MostRecentVersionIndex`. (NOT shown above)
2. This email has a massive amount of records in its body (about 0.5 million characters) and the second part of my code (shown above) consists in putting each single record in a new row of column A from Sheet 1 . I know that each record starts with "SCA" that's why I used it as a split parameter.

Issue : It takes (unsurprisingly) about 10 minutes to run the whole thing.

Any idea on how to reduce this ?

EDIT : Here is FYI the whole code (AFTER THE UPDATE WITH THE SOLUTION) :

```
Sub MailFinder()
'1)Finding the most recent mail from Mr. Spoke
    Dim Inbox As folder
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim MostRecentVersionIndex As Integer
    MostRecentVersionIndex = -1
    Dim TimeReceived As Date
    Dim Content As String
    Set Inbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    For i = 1 To Inbox.Items.Count

            If TypeName(Inbox.Items(i)) <> "ReportItem" Then ' to avoid errors because we can't access information from this type of file
                If Left(Inbox.Items(i).Subject, 24) = "Mr. Spoke Subject" Then 'And Inbox.Items(i).SenderName = "Mr.Spoke" Then
                      'MsgBox Len(Inbox.Items(i).body) '584512
                      If Inbox.Items(i).ReceivedTime > TimeReceived Then
                            TimeReceived = Inbox.Items(i).ReceivedTime
                            MostRecentVersionIndex = i
                      End If
                      'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") = Inbox.Items(i).body ' only get 32000 characters

                End If
            End If
    Next i

'2)Retrieving its information and storing each line in a new row from column A
    Dim position As Long
    Dim CellRow As Long
    Dim RightMail As MailItem
    Set RightMail = Inbox.Items(MostRecentVersionIndex)
    Dim body As String
    body = RightMail.body
    CellRow = 2
    If MostRecentVersionIndex <> -1 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SpokeSubject").Range("A1") = Left(body, InStr(body, "Name") + 3)

        For position = InStr(body, "Name") To Len(body)
            On Error GoTo Fin
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SpokeSubject").Range("A" & CellRow) = Mid(body, InStr(position, body, "SCA"), InStr(InStr(position, body, "SCA") + 1, body, "SCA") - InStr(position, body, "SCA"))
            CellRow = CellRow + 1
            position = InStr(InStr(position, body, "SCA") + 1, body, "SCA") - 1
        Next position '209333
        'Inbox.Items(i).body.Copy ' doesn't work
        'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
        'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") = Inbox.Items(MostRecentVersionIndex).body ' all in one cell...
Fin:
    End If
    Call Formatter
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried using a few variables to reduce the amount of time spent resolving those references multiple times for every run though the loop?  For example, set a variable to the mail item in question, or better yet, get the Body text into a string variable and loop over that.

Comment: Can you post complete code?

Comment: @0m3r : Ok I will edit the post. This will be only to bring value for those who might be interested though since it is unrelated to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is multiple dot notation taken to its extreme. Read the item first, then its body, and only then loop through the characters.

You need to realize that each time you `call Inbox.Items(MostRecentVersionIndex).body`, Outlook returns the Items collection, scrolls to the index MostRecentVersionIndex, opens the message, then reads its (huge) Body property. You do that 5 or 6 times for no good reason.

```
set Item = Inbox.Items(MostRecentVersionIndex)
body = item.Body
For position = InStr(body, "Name") To Len(body)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & CellRow) = Mid(body, InStr(position, body, "SCA"), InStr(InStr(position, body, "SCA") + 1, body, "SCA") - InStr(position, body, "SCA"))
            CellRow = CellRow + 1
            position = InStr(InStr(position, body, "SCA") + 1, body, "SCA") - 1
        Next position
```

Comment: I am confused, I thought there was a limit of characters we could store in a string but apparently it works.
Also, I thought in order to increase the performance of a code we should use a minimum of variables.
Would the performance be really different if I didn't create the `item` variable but stored the whole thing in `body` rather ?

Comment: In 32 bit you string is limited to 4Gb. Minimizing the number of variables in the best case will do nothing (the compiler still has to create implicit variables to hold the  intermediate results) and in the worst case (like yours) degrade the performance significantly.